# Mongoose findbyid / find({id: "..."}) returning Null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have seen this asked several times, but I haven't found a solution that has worked. I am trying to query a MongoDB using Mongoose .findById and am not getting the expected results. find({id: "..."}) is also not returning anything.

Using find without any parameters displays all of the expected results including id key-value pairs, but I cannot use the id value in the query.

Using mongoose: 5.4.9

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  author: String,
  tags: [String],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

async function getCourses() {
  return await Course
    .find()
}

async function run() {
  const result = await getCourses();
  console.log(result);
}
run();
//Return
    [ { tags: [ 'react', 'frontend' ],
    _id: 5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:43:21.589Z,
    name: 'React Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    isPublished: false,
    __v: 0 },
  { tags: [ 'aspnet', 'backend' ],
    _id: 5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:42:59.605Z,
    name: 'ASP.NET MVC Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    isPublished: true,
    price: 15,
    __v: 0 },
  { tags: [ 'node', 'backend' ],
    _id: 5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:44:01.075Z,
    name: 'Node.js Course by Jack',
    author: 'Jack',
    isPublished: true,
    price: 12,
    __v: 0 },
  { tags: [ 'node', 'backend' ],
    _id: 5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:42:47.912Z,
    name: 'Node.js Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    isPublished: true,
    price: 20,
    __v: 0 },
  { tags: [ 'node', 'backend' ],
    _id: 5a68ff090c553064a218a547,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:47:53.128Z,
    name: 'Node.js Course by Mary',
    author: 'Mary',
    isPublished: false,
    price: 12,
    __v: 0 },
  { tags: [ 'angular', 'frontend' ],
    _id: 5a6900fff467be65019a9001,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:56:15.353Z,
    name: 'Angular Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    isPublished: true,
    price: 15,
    __v: 0 },
  { tags: [ 'express', 'backend' ],
    _id: 5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec,
    date: 2018-01-24T21:42:27.388Z,
    name: 'Express.js Course',
    author: 'Mosh',
    isPublished: true,
    price: 10,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

That code verifies I'm connected to the correct database and retrieving real ids. When I modify the getCourses function as shown below, I get null or an empty array depending on whether I use findById or find({id: "..."}).

```
async function getCourses() {
  return await Course
    .findById('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd')
}
//null

async function getCourses() {
  return await Course
    .find({ id: '5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd' })
}
// []

async function getCourses() {
  return await Course
    .find({ _id: '5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd' })
}
// []
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Showing full find() response.

Comment: Would you be able to show the full response from the .find({})? It might help me a bit to see how it’s stored in the database

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Comment: Collection name in MongoDB ?

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr courses

Comment: Try `mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema, 'courses');`

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Did not work.

Comment: I have discovered that if I create a document, the id key is set to Object id and then it does work, but I can't seem to update the value type within Mongo Compass. It remains as a string.

Comment: Same code working fine for me, How your inserting your data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187964/discussion-between-brian-gwaltney-and-siv-sankr).

Comment: If you try running the query { _id : ObjectId('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd') } in mongoDB’s compass, does it return a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon our discussion as your importing the data from JSON file, So its inserting the `_id` as string, While finding the document by `_id`, moognoose automatically converting string to Object.

```
// Original JSON
{
    "_id": "5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e",
    "tags": [
        "aspnet",
        "backend"
    ],
    "date": "2018-01-24T21:42:59.605Z",
    "name": "ASP.NET MVC Course",
    "author": "Mosh",
    "isPublished": true,
    "price": 15,
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Solution 1 :**

To insert the `_id` as in the JSON, change your `_id` field with [$oid](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid) as below,

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e" },
    "tags": [
        "aspnet",
        "backend"
    ],
    "date": "2018-01-24T21:42:59.605Z",
    "name": "ASP.NET MVC Course",
    "author": "Mosh",
    "isPublished": true,
    "price": 15,
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Solution 2 :**

Remove `_id` from your JSON, MongoDB will generate a `_id` automatically

```
{
    "tags": [
        "aspnet",
        "backend"
    ],
    "date": "2018-01-24T21:42:59.605Z",
    "name": "ASP.NET MVC Course",
    "author": "Mosh",
    "isPublished": true,
    "price": 15,
    "__v": 0
}
```